# Is it possible to use Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword in Stitch Custom Authentication/ Stitch Auth

Tags: mongodb, firebase-authentication, custom-authentication

I would like to use Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword to authenticate user in a mongodb Stitch application. Is it possible?

I've researched about Stitch Custom Authentication using JWT Signing key. But I don't know if it's possible to get a JWT Signing key from Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword method

Answer (score 3):

You can use firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword with stitch custom authentication. All firebase auth responses contain a JWT token created by firebase which you can get using the `response.user.getIdToken()` call. This token can then be sent to `stitch` for custom token authentication.

The keys used by firebase are available as JWK uri - https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com.

Also the `aud` defined in the token is the `appId` of your firebase application. This gets validated by stitch and can be defined in the auth configuration tab.

This can be configured in your custom authentication configuration in stitch.